# What does the code below do? Sample image is converted to ycbcr

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
nspace1=rgb2ycbcr(ims);
nspace2= rgb2ycbcr(imt);
ms=double(nspace1(:,:,1));
mt=double(nspace2(:,:,1));
m1=max(max(ms));
m2=min(min(ms));
m3=max(max(mt));
m4=min(min(mt));
d1=m1-m2;
d2=m3-m4;

% Normalization
dx1=ms;
dx2=mt;
dx1=(dx1*255)/(255-d1);
dx2=(dx2*255)/(255-d2);
[mx,my,mz]=size(dx2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're processing two images (`ims` and `imt`) in exactly the same manner, I'l (try to) describe what each line does. You can of course also find this yourself if you look through the documentation yourself / use your brain / [execute the code step by step](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/ug/debugging-a-matlab-function-block.html) and examine variables each step..

```
nspace1=rgb2ycbcr(ims);
ms=double(nspace1(:,:,1));
```

From [rgb2ycbcr documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/rgb2ycbcr.html):

> ycbcrmap = rgb2ycbcr(map) converts the RGB values in map to the YCbCr color space. map must be an M-by-3 array. ycbcrmap is an M-by-3 matrix that contains the YCbCr luminance (Y) and chrominance (Cb and Cr) color values as columns.

So `nspace1` contains the YCbCr values for each RGB input from your image `ims`.
The second line, extracts for each pixel, the 1st element of that YCbCR triplet, being the luminance as you can read above.

```
m1=max(max(ms));
m2=min(min(ms));
```

The first `max` finds the maximum value of each column, so it leaves you with a row. The second `max` finds the max of that resulting row, which leaves you with the absolute maximum of the whole matrix. Same thing for `min(min(...))`.

```
d1=m1-m2;
```

which is then the numeric range of the luminance.

```
dx1=ms;
dx1=(dx1*255)/(255-d1);
```

is supposed to be a normalization as the comment suggests, but it sure doesn't look like a normalization. I think this should be:

```
dx1 = (ms-m2)*255/d1;
```

which transforms every luminance value to a value between 0 and 255.

```
[mx,my,mz]=size(dx2);
```

I leave the last up to you to figure out, shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: +1: more generally you can linearly map the luminance (or any interval of values for that matter) to any `range=[low high]` between two values by `dx1 = abs(range(2)-range(1))*(ms - m2)/d1 + min(range)`

Comment: @Mark Ransom Than what about the division by `255-d1`.. still wrong imo

Comment: @GuntherStruyf of course you're right, I'll delete my comment. Easy to see how it fails if you use m1=255 and m2=0.